# Djangoで能動的になにか処理をするには

Tags: python, django

Djangoを勉強し始めて、HTTPリクエストに対してHTMLを返したり、データベースに保存したりすることはできるようになったのですが、何もしなくても定期的にほかのwebページの情報を取ってきて、自分自身のデータベースをアップデートするようなことをするにはどうすればいいですか？

Djangoとは別にそれ専用のプログラムを作って、そいつにデータベースを更新させるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django commandを実装してOSのcrontabから実行するのではどうでしょう？手軽なので特に問題なければ最初はこれで十分かなと思います。

Pythonで、ということであれば[Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)などを使いましょう。
CeleryならDjangoとの連携機能もあって、始めるにはよさそうです。

[APScheduler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/APScheduler)というのもあります。個人的にはDjangoなどのWebアプリケーションプロセスと組み合わせるのはお勧めできませんが、こちらでがんばってる人もいるようです。